# Conditional Probability - Basic Question

Tags: probability

On question 2b. below, why does knowing the extra bit of information A increase the probability of D?

[image]

Comment: Because you now need to calculate D not out of all possible scenarios, but only out of those scenarios where at least one item is forged. Since there are some scenarios where no item is forged, the number of scenarios where at least one item is forged is smaller than the total number of scenarios. In other words, the denominator in the calculation of D becomes smaller, hence D becomes larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because now the sample space is reduced. The sample space now no longer contains the event that all 5 paintings are authentic. Considering that the probability of none being a forgery is as large as 0.76, and as this event is ruled out, there would be a definite change in the other probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

From the question I get the feeling that you want an answer regarding intuition and not so much mathematics. If I'm wrong, please comment and I will change my answer.

From the probabilities given, we see that it is much more likely that the whole shipment consists of forgeries (10%) than it is likely that only 2,3 or 4 paintings are forgeries (2%, 1% and 2%). Hence, knowing that there is at least 1 forgery in the shipment, increases the chance that the whole shipment is "tainted".

Answer (score 1):

In general:
$$P(D)=P(D\mid A)P(A)+P(D\mid A^c)P(A^c)$$

Here $A^c$ denotes the event that there are no forgeries in the shipment. Under that condition it cannot be that all paintings are forgeries. So $P(D\mid A^c)=0$ and we end up with:$$P(D)=P(D\mid A)P(A)$$
This equality makes clear that $P(A)<1$ implies $P(D\mid A)>P(D)$.